# How to activate worksheet using set range variable

Tags: vba, excel

How can I activate worksheet using set range variable?

For example:

```
Dim WorkRng1 as Range

Range.WorkRng1.Activate
```

This code doesn't work if I'm using range variables between two workbooks.

I'm setting these ranges in different workbooks:

```
Dim xTitleId As String
xTitleId = "Compare Ranges"
Set WorkRng1 = Application.InputBox("Please Select TASK ID Range in **INVOICE REVIEW FILE**", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Please Select TASK ID Range in **BUDGET GRID**", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng3 = Application.InputBox("Please Select **UNIT COST** Range in Budget Grid", xTitleId, Type:=8)

Call CompareRanges
'Error Handler
Whoa:
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 1004
                MsgBox "Check Your Column Letters!", vbInformation, "Oops!"
            Case 424
                Exit Sub
        End Select
```

Then running these loops which happen in different workbooks:

```
'clears color format
WorkRng2.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
'finds duplicate values
For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If Rng1.Value = Rng2.Value Then
            Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(254, 255, 255)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
'find unique values and highlights red
For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
    For Each Rng3 In WorkRng3
        If Rng2.Value > 0 And Cells(Rng2.Row, Rng3.Column) <> 0 And Rng2.Interior.Color <> VBA.RGB(254, 255, 255) Then
            Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
'prompts to select blank row to copy
    Set blkRow = Application.InputBox("Please select the 'BLANK' with formulas", "BLANK ROW SELECTION", Type:=8)
'****NEED HELP HERE
'finds unit id below unique value in range 1 and inserts blank row

'i is range 1
Dim i As Variant
'q is range 2
Dim q As Variant

For i = WorkRng1.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    For q = WorkRng2.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(q, WorkRng2.Column).Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 0, 0) And Cells(q, WorkRng2.Column).Value > 0 Then
            If Cells(i, WorkRng1.Column).Value = Cells(q, WorkRng2.Column).Offset(1, 0).Value Then
                blkRow.Copy
                Cells(i, WorkRng1.Column).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I need to activate the workbook between the groups of loops.

Comment: you need to activate the sheet first.

Comment: @ScottCraner how can i do that with the defined variable range? i won't always be using with the same workbooks

Comment: Then I do not understand what you are to achieve.  A range variable includes the reference to the workbook and work sheet.  It is part of the variable.

Comment: @ScottCraner I will set the ranges with input boxs. I will use multiple ranges from different sheets. When I'm working in a range I would like to activate the worksheet for my loops

Comment: you are not including a [MCVE]  we can't possibly help unless you do so.

Comment: @ScottCraner please see big edit above which included my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the **Range**, but not the **Worksheet** for the range, then you can activate it by using the `.Parent` property of the range.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Worksheets(2).Range("A2")
rng1.Parent.Activate
```

But you can easily avoid this issue by properly declaring your Worksheet objects and using these before setting your Range objects.